# Weka Evaluation Arguments 0/1

Tags: java, weka, smo

May I know what is the argument need to sset in ()? 0 or 1? My datasets have three classes.

```
System.out.println("False Negative % = " + eval.falseNegativeRate(1));
System.out.println("True Negative % = " + eval.trueNegativeRate(1));
System.out.println("True Positive % = " + eval.truePositiveRate(1));
System.out.println("Accuracy % = " + accuracy);
System.out.println("Precision % = " + eval.precision(1));
System.out.println("Recall % = " + eval.recall(1));
System.out.println("F-Measure % = " + eval.fMeasure(1));
System.out.println("Error rate % = " + eval.errorRate());
```